# AngularJs $http request stays pending and does not return value from the database

Tags: node.js, angularjs, rest

I am currently writing a route which allows me to recieve information from a stored procudre I have in a database. I have written a request in AngularJS and a route in NodeJS but I am just recieving a pending request in the chrome Network developer window. I can see that the console.log in the NodeJs app has the data I require so it has retrieved it but there is nothing coming back in any of the console logs in the the AngularJS app.

Here is the code for the both the angularJS app and the Node App:

AnglaurJS:

```
checkForReplenishmentEmptyTrolley = async () => {
        LIBRIS.extensions.openLoadingModal();
        console.log('in checkForReplenishmentEmptyTrolley');
        try {
          const varPromise = await $http.get(`${LIBRIS.config.stockService}stockMovement/checkForUnattachedTrolley`)
            .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            // Request completed successfully
            }, (error) => {
            // Request error
            console.log(error);
            });
          console.log(varPromise.data);
          // 1. check that there are no ghost replenish - lines 1-15
          console.log('in try/catch');
          console.log('promise', varPromise);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      },
```

NodeJS code:

```
app.get(`${ROUTE}/attachTrolley`, async function(req, res){
  const newRequest = await DB.newRequest();
  console.log('we have made it to the route');
  try {
    console.log('we have made it to the Try/Catch route');
    newRequest.input();
   const record = await newRequest.execute('dbo.usp_STK_CheckForUnattachedTrolley');
    res.json(record)
    console.log(record, 'record');
  } catch (err){
    handleError(res, err);
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: The ES6 promises returned by `async`/`await` are not integrated wth the AngularJS framework. AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing a `.then` on a awaited promises and not returning anything from that. You have two choice here

- Either return response from then so when you try to access the value here `console.log(varPromise.data);` it works.
- Or remove the `.then` alltogather as it is not required because you are awaiting it any ways.

Basically just do this

```
checkForReplenishmentEmptyTrolley = async () => {
  LIBRIS.extensions.openLoadingModal();
  console.log("in checkForReplenishmentEmptyTrolley");
  try {
    const varPromise = await $http.get(`${LIBRIS.config.stockService}stockMovement/checkForUnattachedTrolley`);
    console.log(varPromise.data);
    // 1. check that there are no ghost replenish - lines 1-15
    console.log("in try/catch");
    console.log("promise", varPromise);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Hope this fixes your issue.

Comment: I got similar question. Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72969978/not-able-to-parse-data-from-node-file-to-angular-controller-using-promise

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! I had no return statement in my route!

Comment: Please provide the solution